# Character set CP850 with Sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: character-encoding, sybase, sap-ase

I got a Sybase ASE database dump and restored it in my Sybase server.

Database server character set: Cp850

I tried to use Sybase dbisql (Interactive SQL GUI) to connect to database and select from tables that contain Arabic data, I found that all Arabic characters not able to be displayed.

Also I got the same issue while using jTDS to connect to Sybase database using Talend Open Studio for data integration.

While I tried to use Power Builder 12 to connect to the same Sybase server and I can read the Arabic characters without doing any special configuration.

I tried to use "charSet" property in JDBC connection for jTDS, "charSet=Cp850;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false".

Is there any explanation about that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is cp850 going to work on either Server or Client if you want Arabic?

For an 8 bit character set I think you need the sort-order on the server to be one of the Arabic ones, see:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1570/html/sag1/sag1501.htm

Then your client either should have no translation, or one of the Group 6 Arabic character sets, as appropriate (CP 864, CP 1256, ISO 8859-6.)  They'd have an identifer for the client like cp864 or cp1256 or iso88596 I'd think.

Comment: I tried to change sort-order on the server
charset -Usa -P binary.srt cp1256
isql -Usa -P
sp_configure 'default sortorder id', 50, 'cp1256'

but still I can read arabic data only from Powerbuilder only, And couldn't read the Arabic characters from DBISQL or any application using jTDS or jConnect

Comment: First check that your arabic characters are in the database.  Use bcp to unload a table with arabic characters in columns, and use octal dump "od -x" to view them and be sure that you see (codings are in the wikipedias for cp1256 or ISO/IEC 8859-6 depending which you're using.)  Also you could view that in Word for Windows appropriately set up.

Comment: Then if you know that the Arabic characters are there correctly, either don't convert when reading from the server or only convert to a character set that can also do Arabic characters (I don't know how you specify no or some character set conversion for DBISQL or jTDS.)  Lastly what is displaying the characters?  You have to be sure that whatever it is (unix terminal, sql front end, editor, word processor) it is capable of displaying Arabic, and is configured to display the character set you are using.

Comment: Character sets are surprisingly hard.  Read Joel's excellent article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean 'DBISQL', since 'dbisql' is a Watcom(SQL Anywhere) client that cannot connect to an ASE server.
Anyway, it is a character set conversion issue, since other clients apparently display it correctly. So you need to figure out the charset conversion flags for DBISQL. You can also use 'isql' with the -J flags as well for example, but when you run this from the command line, non-ASCII chars may not be displayed correctly (not due to the client, but to the terminal caps of the command-line session).

Comment: When I use DBISQL I specify charSet cp850 also, but still couldn't display Arabic letters.
Power Builder is the only App I succeed to display Arabic characters with it.

Comment: I think this problem somehow is related to ODBC connection,
As powerbuilder using ODBC connection not JDBC.
I'll try to create an ODBC connection same as powerbuilder do to connect to sybase, and then use java odbc bridge to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved completely by using ODBC connection to Sybase.
My Solution: I create ODBC connection at system sdn data sources at Windows, and used this ODBC connection in JDBC-ODBC Bridge, I got the right characters.
Also I tried to create a MS SQL Server Linked server using this ODBC connection and retrieved the data with right characters.
Thanks for you All.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue but later got it solved. below is the full codes using AseConnection option .

```
  [HttpPost("TestConnection")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Connection(ConnectionDetail param)
        {
            var rtv = new ConnectionResponse();
            try
            {
                //Below is the connectionString. You can replace the values accordingly to suit your database connection
                string connstring = $"Data Source={param.IP}; port={param.Port};database={param.DataBaseName};uid={param.UserName};pwd={param.Password};charset=iso_1;Min Pool Size=200;Max Pool Size=5000; ConnectionIdleTimeout=60;";

                //Try to add line 143 to your code before making calls to connect to your sybase. this would solve the issue

                System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
                using (AseConnection theCons = new AseConnection(connstring))
                {
                    await theCons.OpenAsync();

                    //fetch or add record to your sybase database

                    rtv.ErrorCode = 0;
                    rtv.sErrorText = "Connected Successfully!";

                    await theCons.CloseAsync();
                    await theCons.DisposeAsync();

                    return Ok(rtv);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var exM = ex.Message == null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
                rtv.ErrorCode = -1;
                rtv.sErrorText = "Error while connecting to Sybase";

                rtv.sErrorText = exM;
                return BadRequest(rtv);
            }
        }
```